# Can I change the opacity of a UIBarButton item using UIAppearance?

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem

Im able to change the back button tint colour using this appearance proxy

```
//set back button tint
    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:56.0/255.0 green:75.0/255.0 blue:134.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
```

I want to know if it is possible to change the opacity of the back button?

Answer (score 0):

This will allow the whole navigation bar to have some opacity

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTranslucent:YES];
```

Comment: One way to do it would be to make a custom back button of of an image, then set the alpha